# Why do we need continuity in this theorem of path independence of limit of multi variable function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$, where $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that a deleted neighborhood of a point $(a,b)$ is contained in $D$. If $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=L$ exists then

For any real **continuous** function $g$ if $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=b$ then
$\lim_{x\to a}f(x,g(x))=L$

My question is,
Why is the continuity of $g$ required ? Here is how I attempted proof :

For any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta_1>0 : |x-a|<\delta_1 , |u-b|<\delta_1, (x,u)\neq (a,b)\implies|f(x,u)-L|<\epsilon$
And for the function $g$, $\exists\delta_2>0 : 0<|x-a|<\delta_2 \implies|g(x)-b|<\delta_1$

Hence, $\exists\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2) > 0 : 0<|x-a|<\delta$

$\implies 0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ and $0<|x-a|<\delta_2$

$\implies 0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ and $|g(x)-b|<\delta_1$

$\implies |x-a|<\delta_1$ and $|g(x)-b|<\delta_1$ ; $(x,g(x))\neq (a,b)$

$\implies|f(x,g(x))-L|<\epsilon$

Which step from the above requires continuity ?

Comment: Continuity of $g$ is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply :D.

Comment: Deleted neighbourhood? What do you mean, please?

Comment: @dmtri a deleted neighbourhood is typically a neighbourhood of a point with that point removed

Answer (score 2):

Just to close this question, as Kavi Rama Murthy mentioned, the continuity of $g$ is not required in this proof.